# Which material to use for filling those gaps?

Tags: wallpaper

After removing all the wallpaper and some wooden bars that were nailed at the corner of the walls and ceiling all around the room, I now have space that require to be filled at some points (ceiling - wall corner).

The space is like 3 to 8cm deep. What is the best material to use for filling that type of space?

[image: Picture #1]

[image]

Comment: Are you willing to put crown moulding up, or are you specifically looking for a way to finish it without just hiding it?

Comment: what material is the wall?

Comment: I'm renting so I just want to hide it, something quick and easy. The wall is hard concrete I think.

Comment: "wooden bars that were nailed at the corner of the walls and ceiling" = crown moulding?

Comment: If you are renting why don't you have the landlord fix?  Can't have holes in walls.

Comment: DA01: Yes, crown moulding. DMoore: because I created these holes by removing the moulding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the texture goes on the ceiling, you're supposed to mud and tape those joints so there aren't any gaps, and there shouldn't be that much of a gap to start with on drywall. Though perhaps this is something other than drywall.

To fill the gaps now, you've got several options, joint compound, spackling, caulk, or put back up some trim. However, without tape, joint compound is going to crack. Spackling is designed for much smaller gaps. Caulk will allow the two surfaces to move without cracking, but it will never have a smooth look over this large of a gap.

The only two "right" ways to fix this that I can see are to put back up some trim/crown molding, or to knock off the texture on the ceiling so you can fill with joint compound and tape it. If you do the latter, you'd need to knock off a 12" span of the texture, and it's difficult to replace that with something that looks the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Great Stuff](http://www.lowes.com/ProductDisplay?partNumber=15634-236-230612&langId=-1&storeId=10151&productId=1036803&catalogId=10051&cmRelshp=req&rel=nofollow&cId=PDIO1) to fill the gap. It's easy and quick. It might not be the best solution, but it is very cheap. After you use it, then you could joint compute or [vinyl spackling](http://www.lowes.com/pd_41517-68-12130_0__?productId=3822899&Ntt=spackling%20compound&pl=1&currentURL=?Ntt=spackling%2bcompound&facetInfo=) to smooth out the joint.

Comment: If the great stuff expands too much, you're going to be cleaning it off the walls. They make foam backer rods of various diameters to fill joints like this, but they are typically used before caulking.